# Can any "lxc-*" commands list the searching template path?

Tags: linux, virtualization, lxc

Can any `lxc-*` commands list the searching template path? Since in some OSs, the path is `/usr/share/lxc/templates/`, while in others, it may be `/usr/local/share/lxc/templates/`.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done with LXC command, since template storage depend on storage disks that you can choose their role.
So to create a container you should pickup a disk and a location